# Buffer error on using compress

Tags: c, linux, zlib

I seem to be failing after following the example from [here](http://cis.poly.edu/cs912/gzip.txt).

```
#define CHECK_ERR(retcode, msg) { \                                             
  if (retcode != Z_OK) { \                                                      
    fprintf(stderr, "%s on using %s\r\n", zError(retcode), msg); \              
    exit(1); \                                                                  
  } \                                                                           
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
  Bytef a[1000];                                                                
  Bytef b[1000];                                                                
  Bytef c[1000];                                                                
  uLongf compressed_size;                                                       
  uLongf uncompressed_size;                                                     
  int retcode;                                                                  
  size_t i;                                                                     

  uncompressed_size = 800;                                                      
  for (i = 0; i < uncompressed_size; i++) {                                     
    a[i] = ((uint8_t)i) & 255;                                                  
  }                                                                             

  retcode = compress(b, &compressed_size, a, uncompressed_size);                
  CHECK_ERR(retcode, "compress");                                               
  retcode = uncompress(c, &uncompressed_size, b, compressed_size);              
  CHECK_ERR(retcode, "uncompress"); 
}
```

I get a buffer error: [Z_BUF_ERROR](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Constants) (-5)

Program returns:

`buffer error on using compress`

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: error made more explicit

Comment: Pleas tell exactly what the program outputs. Your code should be telling if it's in `compress` or in `uncompress`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I get no error.  I had to add at the top:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "zlib.h"
```

Answer (score -1):

I've edited Your question, adding required includes. 
It's worth mentioning that also -lz should be given to linker.
I've checked that indeed You are getting errors with this code.
However replacing

```
  Bytef a[100];
  Bytef b[100];                                                                
  Bytef c[100];
```

with

```
  Bytef *a = calloc(100, sizeof(Bytef));
  Bytef *b = calloc(100, sizeof(Bytef));
  Bytef *c = calloc(100, sizeof(Bytef));
  if (NULL == a || NULL == b || NULL == c) exit(1);
```

and adding debug

```
  for (i = 0; i < uncompressed_size; i++) {
    a[i] = ((uint8_t)i) & 255;
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  retcode = compress(b, &compressed_size,(const Bytef*) a, uncompressed_size);
  CHECK_ERR(retcode, "compress");
  for (i = 0; i < compressed_size; i++) {
    printf("%d ", b[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  retcode = uncompress(c, &uncompressed_size, b, compressed_size);
  CHECK_ERR(retcode, "uncompress");
  for (i = 0; i < uncompressed_size; i++) {
    printf("%d ", c[i]);
  }
```

yields correct:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
120 156 99 96 100 98 102 97 101 99 231 224 228 226 230 225 229 227 23 16 20 18 6 0 5 70 0 191 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Comment: Dear Downvoter, would You care to explain what's wrong? I assume You tested OP's question Yourself and found better explanation, so I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I tried your exact code and it fails also, in the same way.

Comment: You should explain how your answer supposedly fixes the problem. There is no reason why zlib shouldn't work on stack buffers.